# querySelector returns String instead of DOM-Element

Tags: javascript

I tried to parse the color-names on this page: http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#

Using this code:

```
var all = document.querySelectorAll(".color-group");

for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++){
    var e = all[i];
    var name = e.querySelector('span.name');
    console.debug(name.innerHTML);
}
```

However the printed result is always `undefined`.

This slightly changed code however works:

```
var all = document.querySelectorAll(".color-group");

for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++){
    var e = all[i];
    var name = e.querySelector('span.name').innerHTML;
    console.debug(name);
}
```

The only difference is that I access the result of `querySelector` directly and not via the `name`-variable.

I tried it with Chrome, Safari and Firefox which all did not return the color-names. IE however manged to get it right this time.

Is this a general bug or feature or is it a problem with the website?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're running that code in the global scope, the variable `name` conflicts with that of `window.name` (which is a string); consider creating a scope:

```
(function() {
    var all = document.querySelectorAll(".color-group");

    for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++){
        var e = all[i];
        var name = e.querySelector('span.name');
        console.debug(name.innerHTML);
    }
}());
```

Or, just run that code inside a regular named function and call that from the global scope.

Comment: Thank you. TIL that only functions have a real scope and that only IE lets you overwrite the type of ``name``.

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is something special about variable `name`.

```
var name = 3; name
// => "3"
var dame = 3; dame
// => 3
```

This behaviour is exhibited even by a blank tab (in Chrome at least). If you name your variable something else, it will go away. I believe (!) the reason is that you're executing in console, and `name` always refers to `window.name`; it goes away if you run it in a script; but I am not 100% sure my explanation is the correct one.